# Show that $x^{\alpha}$ is uniformly continuous on $[1, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Fix an $0 < \alpha < 1$ and consider $f(x) = x^{\alpha}$. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[1, \infty)$.

Work so far: If $\alpha = 1/2$, then we can prove $f$ is uniformly continuous since $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| = |x - y|/|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}|$. Similarly if $\alpha = 1/n$, we can write
$$|x^{1/n} - y^{1/n}| = \frac{|x - y|}{|x^{1 - 1/n} + x^{1 - 2/n}y^{1/n} + \cdots + y^{1 - 1/n}|}$$ and we are done. However, this method doesn't seem to work for let's say $\alpha = \sqrt{2}/2$. How does one show $f$ is uniformly continuous for general $\alpha$?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$f'(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$$ is bounded in absolute value by $\alpha$ over $[1,\infty)$. Thus $f$ is Lipschitz over $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: Argh! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Just a couple hours to go! (Or one more accept sooner than that!)